# Angular 7 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to filter an array in angular, I get the following console error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

My class code is here below

```
export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
  public cacheForecasts: WeatherForecast[];
  public summaries: any[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(BaseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));

    http.get<any[]>(BaseUrl + 'api/SampleData/GetSummaries').subscribe(result => {
      this.summaries = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
}

  filterForeCasts(filterVal: any) {
    if (filterVal === '0') {
      this.forecasts = this.cacheForecasts;
    } else {
      this.forecasts = this.cacheForecasts.filter((item) => item.summary === filterVal); // <--- error here
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Your `cacheForecast` is never set; so it is undefined all the time. Probably your constructor changed slightly?

Comment: Second thing - object should be cheap to construct, so you'd rather initialize observables in `OnInit` lifecycle phase rather than in `constructor`, see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit

Comment: @JacekLipiec I agree with you, I just tried to keep code as it was previously working, now after I added OnInit implementation cacheForecasts is no more undefined but get only empty arrays after filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Try initialize cacheForecasts: WeatherForecast[] to an empty array. If the getWeather request of the constructor call fails, then cacheForecasts will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the constructor was missing the filtering array initialization, so the below code worked just fine:

```
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(BaseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
      this.cacheForecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));

    http.get<any[]>(BaseUrl + 'api/SampleData/GetSummaries').subscribe(result => {
      this.summaries = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```